# Não consigo atribuir o valor do campo input digitado pelo usuário à uma variável

Tags: javascript, firebase

Eu sou um novato em programação e estou criando um formulário para coletar dados de usuários e depois enviar esses dados para o Firebase Database.

Eu estou coletando os dados inseridos no HTML pelos campos de input com uma função da forma abaixo:

```
var nomeCandidato = function () {
    return document.getElementById('nameField').value.toUpperCase()
    }
```

O problema que estou tendo é que não consigo atribuir o resultado dessa função para uma variável:

```
var nomesParaCorte = nomeCandidato()
```

Mas quando eu verifico no console do browser com um console.log, a variável 'nomesParaCorte' aparece como 'undefined'.
Se no console do browser eu atribuir dessa mesma forma (var nomesParaCorte = nomeCandidato()) a variável, eu consigo fazer a tribuição do resultado da função.

Eu ficaria muito contente com a ajuda...
Agradeço desde já atenção de todos.

Eu estou intrigado porque não consigo usar os dados coletados do formulário, mas não tenho problemas para atribuir o resultado de uma função a uma variável:

```
//Data do Cadastro
function dataHoje () {
    const hoje = new Date
    const ano = hoje.getFullYear()
    const mes = hoje.getMonth()
    const dia = hoje.getDate()

    return ano + '-' + (mes+1) + '-' + (dia)
}
var diaHoje = dataHoje()
```

Inicialmente eu escrevi todo o código para coletar os dados do formulário e em todos os teste que eu fiz, eu conseguia coletar os dados, conseguia manipular esses dados e depois enviava para o Firebase Database sem problemas.

Eu só percebi que não estava conseguindo coletar os dados do formulário corretamente para utilizar no código depois de ter implementado no código o envio de imagens para o Firebase Storage e depois de enviar as imagens, coletar os URLs para download.

Eu ainda consigo atribuir os dados coletados do formulário para os campos dos documentos que são enviados para o Firebase Database, mas preciso descobrir o motivo de não conseguir utilizar os dados do formulário.

Answer (score 0):

Existem varias soluções dependendo que você pode aplicar, se você vai chamar esta função somente quando o usuário for enviar o formulário, você pode fazer isso fora de uma função única pra isso e somente na função que vai cuidar do envio. sendo algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
function submitForm() {
  //...
  nomeDoCandidatio = document.getElementById('nameField').value.toUpperCase()
  email = document.getElementByid('emailField').value()
  //...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Washington. Aparentemente eu consigo enviar os dados coletados no formulário de forma correta para o banco de dados, mas eu gostaria de fazer algumas manipulações com o nome para criar um nome para cada cadastro a ser registrado no banco de dados ao enviar os dados e não estou tendo sucesso ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente, quando o mesmo código funciona pelo console do browser e pelo script não funciona, pode ser algo relacionado ao momento que o código é chamado. Javascript é uma linguagem assíncrona, então ela não executa o código de forma ordenada e não bloqueia o código enquanto carrega um elemento, e já vai executando as linhas seguintes. É por essa razão que vc consegue navegar nos sites mesmo que nem todas as imagens e botões estejam carregadas.

Veja se no momento que a função nomeCandidato() é chamado no script, o campo e o valor ainda estão carregando.

Vc pode forçar a página aguardar o carregamento completo antes de chamar nomeCandidato() ou só chamar a função no momento de submeter o formulário

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var nomesParaCorte = nomeCandidato()
})
```

Comment: A função pode estar retornando 'undefined' porque o objeto ainda não existe na página pq ainda não deu tempo dela carregar no momento que vc chama ela document.getElementById('nameField')

Comment: "_Javascript é uma linguagem assíncrona, então ela vai executando linha a linha sem esperar terminar o carregamento de cada linha executada_". Essa afirmação é tremendamente equivocada.

Comment: Obrigado. Tem razão. Não consegui explicar de maneira correta e clara. Pode me ajudar a editar minha resposta?